# elasticsearch node not alive

Tags: elasticsearch, restart

I need some help and I will try and offer as much information as I can as I am unfamiliar with Elasticsearch.
I have received access to a server that has elasticsearch installed and uses I am guessing one node to run the elastic search.
When running docker ps -a I can see the name of the container and it's ID and I can also log into it.
however, in a certain part of the application I am getting this error message:
**production.INFO: Exception at search page No alive nodes found in your cluster**

When digging in a little more I can see the following:

- production.ERROR: No alive nodes found in your cluster {"userId":1639,"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException(code: 0): No alive nodes found in your cluster at /var/www/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:50)*

I am assuming the problem is that there is no connection with the node but all answers I found on the web do not specify how to fix the issue or when I try the fixes I get other errors on my side (systemctl not installed and such).

Can anyone explain how I can restart the nodes through the cli? I know for certain the code was not changed so it has to be something to do with the server.

If anyone can help me out that would be great! thanks for your time

Comment: can you `curl localhost:9200` on your host and see if Elasticsearch reponds?

Comment: I tried that but received curl: (52) Empty reply from server.
Not sure what that means though

Comment: So I ran the stats command sudo docker stats -a <container_name> and found out the cpu is at 200%, might be the issue, not sure yet

Comment: what's your docker config look like?

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was I needed to run -
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

I understand this is to increase virtual memory for the container (I found this in a document that was left in the system).
But I would really appreciate if someone can explain why this issue suddenly appeared and if there is a better solution I can use.